# ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#) design issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api-design

i have an api that works as a middleware between a payment api and clients the structure is something like this

[image]

most of the services available in the payment api have 5 parameters in common so i created a base class that define the 5 parameters and in the constructor of the base class a fill the 5 parameters from the database 
and then i made a class for each services that inherent from the base class and when receiving a request (in Json format) i Deserializ the json into the corresponding class (the Deserialization class the constructor by default)

the problem is that the 5 parameters that i get from the database contains the authentication with the payment api (application-id , application password)
and that will allow any one that knows my url and paths to use the api 
so how can i secure  my api 
ps: i also have a hybrid mobile app that uses java script to consume the api

Comment: transfer user name and password via REST is a bad idea in the first place.  It would be good if you describe what  is EBS, so far it is a black box that accept some unknown parameters and respond with unknown data ...

Comment: i'm not sending user name and password they are alredy in the database and the are for the application to connect to the rest services  Ebs is the payment api and it accepts json format and send the result in json

Comment: That's nothing wrong with you web app, the only thingy is that is public :), you can implement a bearer token based on username and password, or a custom token based on a public and private api key, or you can have both. Here is a great example of custom authentication with hmac signature on request: http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/, search Taiseer Joudeh forum an you will get multiple solutions.